# Is there any way to test occurrence of splash screen in react native using detox?

Tags: react-native, detox

Actually I am planning to use a package named react-native-splash-screen for implementing a splash screen on my app. I am quite confused regarding implementation of test for occurrence of splash screen. Or, should I not be worried about writing test for splash screen at all?

I have thought of writing test for mounting of the first component into the app since if the splash screen is successfully shown, the first component into the app will be rendered.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are correct. Don't worry about writing a test to check that. Also, as you said, if you'd like to, you can assert something like `toBeVisible` on your first component that's going to be rendered after the splash.